# Numbering insensitive to delete row in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

##What I want
I have a to-do list.
I would like to use it by deleting the entire line when I finish the task.
In the first column, I want task sequence numbers that will not respond to a row deletion.

Before delete any row

```
1---A
2---B
3---C
4---D
5---E
```

After delete row number 3

```
1---A
2---B
3---D
4---E
```

##What I tried
Autofill
Fill in the first two lines with a number and then drag down.
The numbers have been filled in, but deleting a row also deletes the task number and thus interrupts the numbering sequence.
https://support.google.com/docs/answer/75509

Custom script
I think the custom script is too complicated and unnecessary and such a task could only be solved by functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Numbering from the first line
`A1=arrayformula(row(A1:A20))`
(i) The line containing the formula must not be deleted.
(!) The first task cannot be deleted.


Numbering from any line (numbering from line 5 is used in example)
`A5=arrayformula(row(A5:A20)-(row()-1))`
(i) The line containing the formula must not be deleted.
(!) The first task cannot be deleted.


Numbering with the option to delete the first task (numbering from line 6 is used in example)
`A5=arrayformula(if(row(A5:A20)-row()=0;"Task number";row(A5:A20)-row()))`
(i) The line containing the formula must not be deleted.

or
`A5=arrayformula( {"Task number";row(A5:A20)-(row()-1)} )`
(i) The line containing the formula must not be deleted.


Task number only if task name is filled (numbering from line 6 is used in example)
`A5=arrayformula(ifs(row(A5:A15)-row()=0;"Task number";not(isblank(B5:B20));row(A5:A20)-row();isblank(B5:B20);""))`
(i) From cell B6 to B20 is expected to write titles or descriptions of task.
(i) The line containing the formula must not be deleted.

or
`A5=arrayformula( {"Task number";if(isblank(B6:B20);"";row(A5:A20)-(row()-1))} )`
(i) From cell B6 to B20 is expected to write titles or descriptions of task.
(i) The line containing the formula must not be deleted.